# How to get only one column changed from SqlTableDependency

Tags: c#, .net, sqldependency

When there is any change in my data table `UserSubsidiaryFunction` (insert, update or delete) I get all table with this code :

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    //using SqlTableDependency
    using (var tableDependency = new SqlTableDependency<UserSubsidiaryFunction>(connectionString, "UserSubsidiaryFunction"))
    {
        tableDependency.OnChanged += TableDependency_Changed;
        tableDependency.OnError += TableDependency_OnError;
        tableDependency.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for receiving notifications . . .");
        Console.WriteLine("Press a key to stop");
        Console.ReadKey();

        tableDependency.Stop();
    }                  
}
```

and :

```
static void TableDependency_Changed(object sender, RecordChangedEventArgs<UserSubsidiaryFunction> e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);

    if (e.ChangeType != ChangeType.None)
    {
        var changedEntity = e.Entity;

        Console.WriteLine($"DML operation : {e.ChangeType}");
        Console.WriteLine($"pk_UserSubsidiaryFunction new value : {e.Entity.fk_Subsidiary}");
        Console.WriteLine($"fk_User : {changedEntity.fk_User}");
        Console.WriteLine($"fk_Subsidiary : {changedEntity.fk_Subsidiary}");
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

But when there is any change I would like to get only a column name who were modified. It is possible with `sqlTableDependency`? If not, it is possible with `SqlDependency`? How? Thanks

Comment: Would this be contained in the `MessageBag` or `UserInterestedColumns` on the `RecordChangedEventArgs`?

Comment: Now, all columns (even columns that have not changed) are in RecordChangedEventArgs, so I can't know which one was changed and which was not

Answer (score 0):

```
var mapper = new ModelToTableMapper<SR_Tbl_Orders>();
            mapper.AddMapping(s => s.Status_Id, "Status_Id");
            ElectDependency = new SqlTableDependency<SR_Tbl_Orders>(connectionString, "SR_Tbl_Orders","", mapper);
            ElectDependency.OnChanged += ElectDependency_OnChanged;
            ElectDependency.Start();
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31288074)